# How do I color bash PS1 prompt from the result of a function

Tags: bash, ps1

I want to set my PS1 prompt to the output from a function, but when I try to include ansi color sequences, bash will think the line length is longer than it actually is and mess up when you type enough after it to go to a new line. Here's what the code looks like:

```
ps1() {
    echo -ne "\033[01;34m$(dirs -0)\033[0m \$ "
}
PS1='$(ps1)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `\[` and `\]` around escape sequences. This tells the shell not to count them when determining the width of the prompt.

```
ps1() {
    echo -ne "\\[\033[01;34m\\]$(dirs -0)\\[\033[0m\\] \$ "
}
```

See [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) for all the special sequences you can use in the prompt (e.g. you can use `\e` instead of `\033` for <kbd>Escape</kbd>, and `\w` for the current directory instead of `$(dirs -0)`).

You need to double the backslashes in these sequences to keep them from being eaten by `echo -e`. But if you just use the escape sequences listed at the above page, you don't really need `-e`, since `bash` will process the escape sequences in `PS1` itself.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. only in PS1='\\[...\\]' does that work.

Comment: I see, it's because `echo -e` tries to interpret the escape sequences.

Comment: I updated my answer.